# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startAngle'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am trying to make a donut chart from data which is fetched via an API. I store the data from the API in a json variable, but otherwise my code is standard.

I understand there have been some TypeErrors due to D3.js version change, but I do not even have anything with startAngle written in the code, yet I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startAngle' of undefined.

The code with this problem is on codepen : http://codepen.io/kvyb/pen/GrYzEB/

Here is the code for reference:

```
var a = ["https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-usd", "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/etc-usd","https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/xmr-usd","https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/icn-usd","https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/dash-usd","https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/MAID-usd","https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/omni-usd","https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/rep-usd"];

function fetch() {
  all_data = ["{\"floor\": ["];
  for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) { 
    $.ajax({
      url : a[index],
      dataType : "json",
      async : false,
      error : function(data){
        console.log("--");   
      },
      success : function(data) {
       all_data += JSON.stringify(data["ticker"]) + ',';
      }
    })
  }
};

fetch() 
all_data += "]}";
var pos = all_data.lastIndexOf(',');
all_data = all_data.substring(0,pos) + "" + all_data.substring(pos+1);
console.log(all_data)

// CHART

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

data = JSON.parse( all_data );

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.base); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.base; });

function type(d) {
  d.price = +d.price;
  return d;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startAngle`, together with `endAgle`, `padAngle`, `index`, `value` and `data`, are properties created by the pie generator. As you're not correctly passing your data to the pie generator, you're getting that error (`undefined` here refers to your data).

You have two problems to fix. First, your `data` variable is an object, and you have to pass an **array** to `data()`. To pass the array, instead of:

```
.data(pie(data))
```

It should be:

```
.data(pie(data.floor))
```

Second, you don't have a property named `population` in the objects of that array. So, change the pie generator to a property that you have in your data, as `volume`:

```
var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return +d.volume;
    });
```

Here is your Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZGyrL?editors=0010